# HttpSession without cookie

Tags: grails

I have an application a the moment which for a particular set of reasons will be interacting oddly with the hosting server.

The application is to be accessed through a larger portal and can be encapsulated within the portal display, however it makes extensive use of AJAX requests which are not intercepted by the portal. These requests are made directly to the hosting server, however I am seeing a problem.

When the first ajax request is made (a little way into the application flow) the Ajax request is not carrying with it the JSessionId cookie (obviously as it's sending this to a different server than it received it from)

Is there a good grails way to find the session the AJAX call should be interacting with. I have tried setting grails.views.enable.jsessionid to true, but this only works if the browser is not accepting cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way will be for you to set up your own "cookie" and pass that along with the requests.

It sounds like you are running into issues due to the portal and it's cookies and then having to continue that "session" onto a different server. Your application needs to simply handle it's own sessions itself in order to prevent getting stomped on by the "normal" cookies.

The idea is essentially to create a session token when the portal makes a request from to your application, and then the subsequent AJAX calls your application makes back to it's own server should include that token. You can then easily associate that token with the session you need to be using.

If you are looking to make it a bit more robust and handle it above the level of your application, you can leverage the fact that Grails is built on Spring MVC deep down and override the default session handler to pick up on whatever mechanism you decide to go with. I'm not sure of exactly how to do this with Grails, but I've done similar things on Spring MVC projects and it isn't too tough once you get your head wrapped around the various injection points of the framework.

It isn't ideal, since there is now a fair bit more complexity, but in theory, the benefits of the portal are outweighing the added complexity required for traditionally "handled" things like sessions and expiring them, etc.

Comment: It seems from his question that the session cookie is not getting passed along from the origin through the portal to the user.  If he can't add a cookie to the main request back through the portal, then this won't work.  If the portal is essentially a dumb proxy, this isn't that surprising unfortunately.

Comment: @PlexQ - Yes, that was why "cookie" is in quotes. It isn't a normal cookie, but it functions like one. That is the entire point of my response... to use an alternate method of identifying to the application which session should be used for a series of requests. In all cases, it's still the same concept, just a different implementation.

Comment: Going for a solution with a 'cookie' as mentioned. I've implemented a session listener and capture the session id, and storing the minimum context I need away in the servletContext under that session key. Then on each ajax request I also pass the session key and validate the request against the sessions present in the servletContext. It's working for one server at the moment but I'll need to revisit for something more robust when I have to scale to multiple servers. I think ehcache replication can be my friend there

Comment: Yes, scaling up to more than 1 server will require you to use a "shared session" strategy of some sort. Thankfully, since you are conceptually still using the "session" concept, you shouldn't have too much trouble extending along the same lines as "normal" sessions do. A shared cache, like you mentioned, is probably a good way to go, but it isn't the only one, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden form input value that has the jsessionid in it on the page you send back to the portal on the first request.  Then read that form variable, and set the cookie in your javascript code that makes the AJAX request.

I'm guessing seeing that this already works, cross-site scripting isn't an issue?  AJAX requests to domains other than that which the main page originated from will be blocked by the browser.